# UITextView in UIScrollView unable to be selected

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have a 3 custom UITextViews inside a UIScrollView. However, I am unable to select the UITextView, because when I tap it, the keyboard doesn't come up, and the `textViewShouldBeginEditing` function is not being called. I have `setUserInteractionEnabled` to `YES` on my UITextViews, but it seems like the UIScrollView is blocking my tap gestures. `[textView becomeFirstResponder]` isn't an option for me, because that simulates the textView being tapped when I didn't even tap it in the first place.

Comment: Strange, I have uibutton in a scroll view and I can tap them without a problem.. Why is it different??

Comment: I have no idea. I am able to tap uitextfields, but not uitextviews,